# ant: resource in jar could not be found. failed to create task or type classpath

Tags: java, xml, ant

I have the following problem in ant:

```
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antcontri
b.properties. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
build.xml:5: Problem:
failed to create task or type classpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Running the following ant build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project default="main" basedir=".">    
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />
    <classpath>
      <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
      </fileset>
    </classpath>

    <target name="main">

    </target >
</project>
```

Although, running

```
<project default="main" basedir=".">    

    <path id="path.svnant">
        <pathelement location="${basedir}/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
    </path>

    <typedef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpathref="path.svnant" />

    <target name="main">

    </target >
</project>
```

Results no errors what so ever.

So the question is why the first build.xml is wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose because `<classpath/>` element must be inside `</taskdef>` element.

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" >
   <classpath>
      <fileset dir=".">
         <include name="**/*.jar" />
      </fileset>
   </classpath>
</taskdef>
```